# could you advice me the right way of migrate database of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

so I have a some situation, I have **2 sites**:

- one site is dev version and
- Second is live version of site.

Some month ago I have copied all things from **Live** site to dev site, and doing many changes in **Dev** version. and then in this time period there are added many posts, products, and also sold products on live site, how to migrate **Database** from **Live** site to dev site without losing data on dev site changes.

Sorry for such as long question . . .

Maybe does it exists some plugin for doing this task?

Comment: Since you want to keep the data on Dev side, it is a complex task. There are Import / Export tools built-in. Try that.

Comment: why don't  you download database from live site and import on dev site. And then run `migrate_query`

Comment: because there are a lot of changes on dev site, added some posts,  changed sliders . . . and other changes, and I am afraid that it will give me duplicate ID s in tables.

Comment: so you are saying you don't want to duplicate live site's contents to dev site but want to import only changes ?

Comment: yes, only that data which doesn't exists in dev site but exists in live site

Comment: hmm it's complex issue. I think you need to import database manually.

Comment: thank you for your comments.